# align 2 DNA sequences and find complementary regions

Tags: string, perl, dna-sequence

I tried to find some clue in the list but I couldn't, so sorry if I ask a repeated topic

I am PERL beginner and I am trying to write a program in PERL that take two DNA sequences, calculate the reverse of the second one and find the maximum complementary regions between them, that is:

input:

```
CGTAAATCTATCTT
CATGCGTCTTTACG
```

output:

```
CGTAAATCTATCTT
GCATTT--------
```

I have no problem to find the reverse of the second sequence, however my programming skills in PERL are rudimentary. Do I need to use a combined for an foreach loops?

Comment: Are you writing the program because you need one, or because it's a homework task/assignment of some sort? In the first case it might be worth taking a look a BioPerl, which probably already contains the functionality you require, or at least part of it.

Comment: There's a whole book about this
"Perl for Exploring DNA"
http://www.oup.com/us/companion.websites/9780195305890/

Comment: i'sorry, that was not my intention, i was trying to get some different approaches where i was stucked in, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you want (crudely):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
die unless @ARGV == 2 && length $ARGV[0] == length $ARGV[1];
my @seq1 = split //, $ARGV[0];
my @seq2 = split //, reverse $ARGV[1];
my @comp;
for my $n (0..@seq1-1) {
    if   ( ($seq1 [$n] eq 'A' && $seq2 [$n] eq 'T') 
        || ($seq1 [$n] eq 'T' && $seq2 [$n] eq 'A') 
        || ($seq1 [$n] eq 'G' && $seq2 [$n] eq 'C') 
        || ($seq1 [$n] eq 'C' && $seq2 [$n] eq 'G') ) {
        push @comp, $seq2[$n];
    }
    else {
        push @comp, '-';
    }
}
print @seq1, "\n", @comp, "\n";
```

...which when run:

```
# ./compseq CGTAAATCTATCTT CATGCGTCTTTACG
CGTAAATCTATCTT
GCATTT------A-
```

Comment: thanks! is more or less the same as the above code, but i find more comprehensible, at least for a beginner like me, thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Does this work for you?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

sub complement {
    $_[0] =~ y/CGAT/GCTA/;
    return $_[0];
}

sub match {
    my ($s1, $s2) = @_;
    $s2 = reverse $s2;
    complement $s2;
    print "$s1\n";
    my $s2l = length $s2;
    for (my $length = $s2l; $length; $length--) { # start from the longest possible substring
        for my $start (0 .. $s2l - $length) {     # starting position of the matching substring
            my $substr = substr $s2, $start, $length;
            my $pos = index $s1, $substr;
            if ($pos + 1) {
                return ('-' x $pos) . complement "$substr" . ('-' x ($s2l - $length - $pos));
            }
        }
    }
}

print match('CGTAAATCTATCTT',
            'CATGCGTCTTTACG')
    ,"\n";
```

Comment: thanks! so the idea is to bind two for loops, however i'm a little bit confused about how it works: i don't get where the two strings are in the loops, the first loop is for the first and the second for the other one?

Comment: Nice.  If you complement `$s1` instead of 2, then you don't have to complement the `$substr` on the way out.

Comment: @user976991, the outer loop iterates over all possible substring sizes for string2.  The inner loop generates all possible substrings of a given length.  As for how the strings are compared see `perldoc -f index` and `perldoc -f substr` ( or http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/index.html and http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr.html )

Comment: imagine you have the 2 sequences with different lengths and you want the best match using sliding windows, I mean, your A sequence is 10 nt and your B sequence 5 nt. So you move each time your B sequence along A and you'll give an score, say 1 if C-G, T-A or inverse and 0 for the rest. Is this correct?